# Powershell sorting data in Invoke-Command results

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm running an exe from invoke-command on multiple servers and it works.  I get a string array with all the output I expect.

`$result = invoke-command $servers { & "\path\toexe" arg1 }`

This gives me the correct results

```
str3
str4
str2
```

...and the `PSCOMPUTER` name is in there too, but I can't show them together so I can't match the result to the `PSComputername` all at once.

`$Result|GM`   just shows me PScomputername and RunspaceID as properties.  It's like the `$result` array has no label for the string.

`$result | Select *`  doesn't show me the string

`$Result.gettype()` shows it is `[object]  System.Array`

I can do `$result[0]` will show me `str3`
And then `$result[0].PSComputername` will show `Server3`

How do I get that whole array on the screen or dumped to csv together?  I'd like to see

```
PSCOMPUTERNAME   ??
Server3        str3
Server2        str2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object` to create new objects consisting of the attached `PSComputerName` property along with a new named property containing the intrinsic value of the original string:

```
$result |Select-Object PSComputerName,@{Name='Value';Expression={"$_"}}
```

To learn more about using `Select-Object` with property expressions, see [the `about_Calculated_Properties` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties#select-object)

Comment: This is nice and easy - I just thought of 10 more uses for this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I usually package the result in an object.  This could be a script too.  Unless the object type has a local view file, there's a runspaceid displayed too.

```
invoke-command $servers { [pscustomobject]@{result = \to` path\toexe arg1} }

result PSComputerName RunspaceId
-----  -------------- ----------
str3   Server3        5f8b7b5e-840d-4790-896a-d68aa23f1c01
str2   Server2        3b37b3d7-f1d0-433a-a387-65c4c3a59a5d
```

```
<# script.ps1 #>
[pscustomobject]@{result = \path\toexe arg1}
```

```
invoke-command $servers script.ps1

# same result
```